# How to open a PIL image on every tkinter button press?

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am very new to Pyton and programming in general, and for my first project i am trying to make a script with Tkinter interface that should do the following:

1. Allow user to write some text into an entry,
2. on button click place that text on an image with a defined name,
3. save that image under the name that is current date and time,
4. repeat all of the above on button click.

The script works properly only once (after the first button click) then it places the entered text on previously entered text.

I gather that's because it opens the initial image only once and does other steps every time the button is clicked, but i can't seem to write the code that defines the initial image into command=lambda (it causes various errors). 
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from datetime import datetime

def adresat1_function(self): draw.text(xy=(273, 215), text=(entry_1.get()),
    fill=(0, 0, 0), font=font_type)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Postal")
root.maxsize(height=530, width=590,)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=530, width=590, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

frame_1 = tk.Frame(canvas, bg='#75a3a3', bd=2)
frame_1.place(x=5, y=10, height=200, width=580, anchor='nw')

entry_1 = tk.Entry(frame_1, font=18,)
entry_1.place(x=202, y=0, width=374, height=22,)

#Image

image = Image.open('Blank.jpg')
font_type = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf',14,)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

#Button

button = tk.Button(frame_1, text = 'Fill', width=8,
    command=lambda:

    #Fill
    (adresat1_function(entry_1.get()),
    image.save(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S") + '.jpg'),))

button.place(x=202, y=160, width=374, height=22,)
root.mainloop()
```

What has to be done to make this program save the entered text on a new image without rewriting it on top of the previously entered text?
I may not even know some of the Python core concepts, in that case sorry for dumb question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying your code like below, will solve the problem. What you want is that every time that you press the button, a new image copy is created and you can apply your text there:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from datetime import datetime

# Changes here.
def adresat1_function(self):
    newImage = image.copy()
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(newImage)
    draw.text(xy=(273, 215), text=(entry_1.get()),fill=(0, 0, 0), font=font_type)
    newImage.save(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S") + '.jpg')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Postal")
root.maxsize(height=530, width=590,)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=530, width=590, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

frame_1 = tk.Frame(canvas, bg='#75a3a3', bd=2)
frame_1.place(x=5, y=10, height=200, width=580, anchor='nw')

entry_1 = tk.Entry(frame_1, font=18,)
entry_1.place(x=202, y=0, width=374, height=22,)

#Image

image = Image.open('Blank.jpg')
font_type = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf',14,)
newImage = None

#Button

button = tk.Button(frame_1, text = 'Fill', width=8,
    command=lambda:

    # Changes in fill.
    (adresat1_function(entry_1.get()),))


button.place(x=202, y=160, width=374, height=22,)
root.mainloop()
```